# AM_ENC_KEY attribute of OpenAM

Tags: openam

According to OpenAM-12.0.0-Install-Guide, User can set up `openAM` by using command "java -jar openam-configurator-tool-12.0.0.jar --file config.properties".There are many key-value pairs in config.properties. But the value of AM_ENC_KEY attribute is NULL. How can I get a random AM_ENC_KEY value? And what does this key encrypt?

Answer (score 1):

If you leave the AM_ENC_KEY value empty in the configuration file, then a random key will be generated for you.

The encryption key is used to encrypt most of the passwords stored within the OpenAM configuration (things like passwords for the data stores, LDAP servers you authenticate against, etc).